# Finding the Domain of a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I have to find the domain of these two functions:

$$ \sin |x|\quad\text{ and }\quad |\sin x| .$$

I do not really know how to find the domain of these two functions. Any help would be great, I am really stuck.

Comment: The domain of a function is the set of all $x$-values that it admits.  Do either of your functions have any points at which they become undefined?  Example: $f(x)=\frac {1}{x}$ is not defined at $0$ so its domain excludes $x=0$

Comment: Imagine you have a value of $x$ in a calculator and you have to compute your expression **one step at a time**.  E.g., for the first you have $x$, then you calculate $|x|$, then $\sin(|x|)$.  Are there any $x$ values where the calculator will tell you "error"?  If so, these $x$ values are not in the domain.  BTW are you 100% sure you understand what $|x|$ means?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)$ takes all values of x and the absolute values don't  influence that, so the domain is all real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value is defined for all real numbers, and the domain of the $\sin$ function is $\Bbb R$.

Thus, the domain of the function $\sin|x|$ is $\Bbb R$ and of $|\sin x|$ is also $\Bbb R$.